# Read binary file by blocks

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, binary-search, vectors

I wrote a function that allow me to read a binary file using 3 blocks what ever the length of file.

I've decided to divide the length of my file into 3:

> block 1: **______________**
>
> block 2: **______________**
>
> block 3: **____**

As you can see, this is almost the length of the 3 blocks that I will have using my function.

(What is important for me is to read all characters in my file)

```
vector< vector<char> >  ReadByBlock(string fileName){

ifstream is (fileName, ifstream::binary);

if (is) {
is.seekg (0, is.end);
int length = is.tellg();
is.seekg (0, is.beg);

cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... "<<endl;                                    
const int bloc = 1+length/3;
vector< vector<char> > vect (3,vector<char>(bloc,0));      // create vector of 3 vector of(1+length/3) chars with value 0   


    for(size_t j=0;j<3;++j)
    {
        is.read(&vect[j][0], bloc); 
        for(size_t i=0;i<bloc;++i)  
            cout << " buf ["<<j<<","<<i<<"]: "<<vect[j][i] << endl;
    }

 return vect;}}
```

Because I'm beginner in the world C++ and because I'm thinking about Java while programming my function, I want to know if it is an efficient function that respects the rules of C++ as well the structure of coding using C++.

Comment: Was there a copy/paste problem?  That entire `if` block isn't indented.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that, please ? 
( If it's a copy/paste problem as you say it means that I'm not in the wrong way, men, and I developed my first fonction in C++ like an expert )

Comment: @SADOK Jamal means that your indentation is off, your `if` block is not indented and Jamal wanted to know whether this was by design or due to the copy-paste in Code Review :)

Comment: It was by design @jamal, 
sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `using namespace std`

Since none of the standard library features you use are prefixed by `std::`, I will assume that you have `using namespace std;` somewhere. Actually, you should [avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1364752) and fully qualify the standard library functions and classes with `std::` instead. Your code won't be much longer, and you may avoid potential problems such as name clashes.

### Use `std::array`

One thing that can be noticed is that you know that you will return a collection of *exactly* three `std::vector<char>`. You know the size at compile time, therefore you don't need a dynamic container, a fixed-sized one is enough. Let's make that explicit and have your function return an `std::array<std::vector<char>, 3>` instead.

### Check for potential errors

`ifstream is (fileName, ifstream::binary);` is great. It's how it should be used. However, it may fail, for example if the file `fileName` does not exist. You should check whether such an error occured before resuming the function:

```
std::ifstream is (fileName, std::ifstream::binary);
if (not is)
{
    // handle errors (e.g. throw an exception)
}
```

Note that `operator!` (here `not`) is used to check for errors. If it yields `false`, it means that an error occured when opening the `std::ifstream`.

### Accessing a `std::vector` underlying array

You used the C++98 way `&vec[0]` to get the underlying array of an `std::vector`. Actually, when reading code, knowing what it does can be pretty hard, and that's partly due to the order of evaluation of the operators that may not be obvious for everyone. You can use `vec.data()` instead. This method was not available for `std::vector` before C++11, and that's probably why you found the solution `&vec[0]`.

Comment: first of all thanks for your clear explanation.
According to "using namespace std", I already used one in my whole code and I will avoid this. :)
According to "containers", I must read my binary file character by character ( because this fonction will be used with other fonction that treat characteres and not string, however I will think about string in my whole project)
Talking about "potential errors", of course I have to treat the risk of fail (my efforts have been rewarded both in C++ and using vector )
Thank you for twice.

Comment: @morwenn, Please can you give me an answer for this question. When someone give me a suggestion to correct my code does I have to correct my question or I must leave it with error for other and then that code detect the errors.

Comment: @SADOK You have to leave the errors in-place. The goal is that other people can read the original code, *then* read the suggestions. Correcting the original code would invalidate the answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Most of what Morwenn said.

Additionally when you specify a return type on a function:

```
   vector< vector<char> >  ReadByBlock(string fileName)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You must also exit the function by returning a value. Not doing so is UB.
If the stream fails to open your code fails to return a value.

```
vector< vector<char> >  ReadByBlock(string fileName)
{
    if (is)
    {
       // All good stuff.
       return vect;
    }

    // But if you fail in the if condition.
    // Then come here and there is no explicit return.
    // this is UB.
}
```

Note: this was hard to spot given the indentation style. So I would really emphasis that you work harder to have a much neater indentation style and write your code much more cleanly.

```
return vect;}}  // This is truly horrible.
```

This is a bit of an optimization but this:

```
vector< vector<char> > vect (3,vector<char>(bloc,0));
```

Actually creates four vectors. A temporary one is created then used to initialize the other three. This seems a bit wasteful. I would just use resize() as they are about to be used.

```
vector<vector<char>> vect(3);

for(size_t j=0;j<3;++j)
{
    vect[j].resize(bloc);   // You could even optimzie this to
                            // make the last vector the exact size needed.
                            // rather than wasting space.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Loki. I understand your observations.
But, about " return vect;}} ", I always find problem to put my code into my question in Stack. " }}" stay out of my code that's why it looks like this.